# How to add icon on right button using react native router flux

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I want to add a `react-native-vector-icon` in place of the right button in the header using react native router flux

Here is my code :

```js
<Scene
    onRight={() => Actions.inbox()} 
    rightTitle='Inbox' 
    key='home'
    component={Home} 
    title='Home'
    icon={HomeIcon}
    initial
/>
```

How to add `react-native-vector-icon` in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it, I used `renderRightButton` for solving it.

here is the example:

```
const InboxIcon = () => {
    return (
        <View style={{ marginRight: 10 }} >
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Actions.inbox()} >
                <Icon
                    name='comment'
                    type='font-awesome'
                    size={30}
                />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
};
```

And in scene I render it. Like this,

```
<Scene
        renderRightButton={InboxIcon}  
        key='home'
        component={Home} 
        title='Home'
        icon={HomeIcon}
        initial
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "rightTitle" prop you can use:

- "rightButtonImage" prop for image
- "renderRightButton" prop for custom components.

Described on: https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API.md#scene